# TFS 2013.2 Licencing Information

Tags: tfs

I work for a medium size corporation that uses TFS2013.2. We have about 130 people who access TFS. This product is unusual for us as it is run and maintained by the development staff, rather than IT pros. A result of this is that there is a greater fear than normal that we may not be meeting our licencing obligations.

Currently, everyone, except Team Administrators, have their permissions allocated via Windows groups and to get added to one of these groups a licence, CAL or MSDN, is allocated to you. Therefore, I am confident we are meeting our obligation. However proving it is beyond me.

Is there a single place I can go to see who has access to TFS? I have found a dbo.tbl_Identities table in the Configuration database, but that seems to contain people seemingly at random from one or more of our domains and anyway contains people who have left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using tfssecurity.exe to list all the valid TFS Groups and group members.  You'd have to clean up the output a bit but domain users should be easy to spot:

```
tfssecurity.exe /imx "Team Foundation Valid Users" /collection:http://tfs2013:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

Alternatively you could use the api

```
TeamFoundationIdentity identity = gss.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "Team Foundation Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded,ReadIdentityOptions.None);
TeamFoundationIdentity[] identities = gss.ReadIdentities(identity.Members, MembershipQuery.Expanded,ReadIdentityOptions.None);
```

Iterate through the list of returned users and do something clever with the results.

Comment: Thanks I've used the tfssecurity command to generate the output that matched what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You manage the license using the page at `http://<your-tfs-address>:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses`. There you find **Export audit log** to check who has access and their license level. In the same page you can assign user to a different licensing level.

Also note that upgrading to Update 4, your get the Stakeholder level which gives a lot to casual users which do not have a TFS CAL.

For more information [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/connect/change-access-levels).

Comment: We have not implemented this feature because it seemed to add complexity and had limited value. Currently, each team is a Windows Group and permissions and work items are allocated via these Teams. If we wanted to use Windows groups for this feature, we would have to have users in two sets of groups one for Web Access permissions and one for other access. I was going to revisit this when we went to TFS2013.4 due to the Stakeholder licence you mention. I do find it complex, and I'm not sure I have worked out all the angles. Thanks for your comment.